# Complex SQL Server 2008R2 column constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008R2 table that drives a collection of UI processes. 
As an "Accidental DBA", I'm looking to impose some data integrity constraints on this table for INSERTS and UPDATES.

The data integrity aspect of this table is paramount, because the app will happily crash on you if there are any exceptions to the rules.

The data integrity rules are also needed because this table will be fairly static, but our admin roster is not.  And the overtired, new, or fragmented admin may not remember all of the (completely documented) rules at such time as table maintenance is needed.

```
-- An excerpt of the table:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#lkupMasterFieldList]
(
   [FieldID]        INT IDENTITY (101,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ,  -- Unique identifier for each row                
   [FieldName]      VARCHAR( 100) NOT NULL,                       -- Output column name and/or MasterFieldList struct name.
   -- ...                                                               
   [AppFieldLabel]  VARCHAR(  50)     NULL,                       -- Name used in the app processes, esp. in creation pick lists of selectable columns. 
   [AppFieldType]   VARCHAR(  15)     NULL,                       -- When not null, one of "assignment", "job" or "-".  for grouping visible pick list fields.  Currently, the dash is used only with JobNumber to select it into the selected field list by default.
   [AppDisplayIdx]  INT           NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,             -- Sorting index value for displaying Column Picker columns in a particular order (other than the apparently random order used today.) Use negative values to ORDER BY (ASC) the default Selected list.
   -- ...   
   [Hidden]         BIT           NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,             -- Hidden = 1 if the field does not appear in the Output Columns pane.  (Typically for admins only)
   [Active]         BIT           NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,             -- Bitflag to indicate whether or not this column is still in use or is obsolete.
   [SelectString]   VARCHAR(1500)     NULL                        -- Columns or subselect query text to be included in the final dSQL SELECT statement. 
)   
GO
INSERT INTO #lkupMasterFieldList
          ( FieldName ,
            AppFieldLabel ,
            AppFieldType ,
            AppDisplayIdx ,
            Hidden ,
            Active ,
            SelectString
          )
VALUES

 -- And a data snippet, for some context...      
('AuditDate'               ,NULL                ,NULL          , 0 , 1 , 1, NULL), 
('Category'                ,'Job Category'      ,'job'         , 12, 0 , 1, '(SELECT UPPER(LabelValue) FROM tJobLabel WHERE tJobLabel.JobID = tJ.JobID AND tJobLabel.LabelTypeID = 1) AS Category,'   ), 
('Change'                  ,NULL                ,NULL          , 0 , 1 , 1, NULL), 
('ClosedDate'              ,'Job Closed Date'   ,'job'         , 19, 0 , 1, 'tJ.ClosedDate,'   ), 
('CommentID'               ,NULL                ,NULL          , 0 , 1 , 1, ''' AS CommentID,'   ), 
('Comments'                ,NULL                ,NULL          , 0 , 1 , 1, ''' AS Comments,'   ), 
('CompOn'                  ,NULL                ,NULL          , 0 , 1 , 1, NULL), 
('CreationDate'            ,'Job Created Date'  ,'job'         , 11, 0 , 1, 'tJ.CreationDate,'   ), 
('CurrentAssignee'         ,NULL                ,'assignment'  , 0 , 1 , 1, ' CASE WHEN ((tR.AssignDate IS NOT NULL) AND (tR.DispositionDate IS NULL) AND (tRL.Status = ''Active'') ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CurrentAssignee,'), 
('CurrentAssigneeWithDate' ,NULL                ,'assignment'  , 0 , 1 , 1, NULL), 
('DateLastModified'        ,NULL                ,NULL          , 0 , 1 , 1, NULL), 
('DateMods'                ,'Job Date Changes'  ,'job'         , 20, 0 , 1, '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tJobDueDate WHERE Jobid = tJ.Jobid) AS DateMods,'   )
 -- 
 --
```

I don't have much experience with this design area, except for creating some unique indexes, simple constraints and defaults.

Of the 20 or so constraints that I've identified for the (complete) table, I've gotten all but the handful below working fine.

What I need here is any advice you might have for implementing any or all of the following rules, or an indication that it can't be done.

- Rule  2. At INSERT time, is it possible to have the default for the `DisplayName` column be the same value entered for the `FieldName` column? The highly undesirable current default is '(Undefined)'.

  Rule  3. `<column>` can be NULL if and only if (`Hidden = 1 or Active = 0`). This type of constraint applies to three columns: `AppFieldLabel, AppFieldType, SelectString`.

  Rule  5. When `NOT NULL`, `AppFieldType` is limited to one of (`'job', 'assignment','-'`)

  Rule  7. `AppDisplayIdx` has default `max(AppDisplayIndex) + 1`

  Rule  8. `AppDisplayIdx` can be less than zero `if AppFieldType = "-"`

  Rule  9. `AppDisplayIdx` can be zero `if Hidden = 1`

  Rule 10. `AppDisplayIdx` can be greater than zero `if (AppFieldType IS NOT NULL AND AppFieldType IN ('job', 'assignment')`

  Rule 14. `AppDisplayIdx` must be distinct, except for zero [This is being handled by a unique nonclustered filtered index.]

So if we wanted to add some new fields

```
INSERT INTO #lkupMasterFieldList
          ( FieldName ,
            AppFieldLabel ,
            AppFieldType ,
            AppDisplayIdx ,
            Hidden ,
            Active ,
            SelectString
          )
VALUES

-- New Field 1
('Deliverable' ,NULL            , 'job'        , NULL , 0 , 1 , '(SELECT LabelValue FROM tTaskLabel AS tTL14 WHERE tTL14.TaskID = tT.TaskID AND tTL14.LabelTypeID = 2) AS Deliverable,'), 
-- New Field 2                   
('Disposition' ,NULL            , 'assignment' , NULL , 0 , 1 , 'ISNULL( (SELECT lkR.Response FROM tJobResponse tJRsp LEFT JOIN lkupResponse lkR ON tJRsp.ResponseID = lkR.ResponseID WHERE tJRsp.RLDID = tR.RLDID ), tR.Disposition ) AS Disposition, ' ), 
-- New Field 3                   
('DeptNumber'  ,'Department'    , 'dept'       ,  0   , 0 , 1 , NULL), 
-- New Field 4                   
('EmpIDOwner'  ,'Job Boss'      , 'emp'        ,  7   , 0 , 1 , 'tJ.EmpIDOwner, '   ), 
-- New Field 5                   
('AssignDate'  ,'Date Assigned' , 'date'       , -7   , 0 , 1 , 'ISNULL(tR.AssignDate, 0) AS AssignDate, ') 

-- Then for Field 1 and Field2, respectively, the 
--    AppFieldLabels would be 'Deliverable' and 'Disposition' (Rule 2) 
--    AppDisplayIdxs would be 21 and 22, (Rule 7) 

-- Field 3 fails because of any of the following:
--    AppFieldType  = 'dept' (Rule 5)
--    AppDisplayIdx = 0      (Rule 9)
--    SelectString  is NULL  (Rule 3)

-- Field 4 fails because 
--    AppFieldType = 'emp' and AppDisplayIdx = 7  (Rule 10)

-- Field 5 fails because 
--    AppFieldType = 'date' and AppDisplayIdx = -7 (Rule  8)
--
--
```

I suspect that some of these rules might be implemented using one or more constraint functions,  But all the examples I've been able to find so far have been really simplistic and not much help.

Thanks for any hints you can provide.

```
-- Cleanup 
DROP TABLE #lkupMasterFieldList
```

Comment: There is an error in your second line of first insert - `Incorrect syntax near 'Category'.` Btw, what is this table for ?

Comment: The table is for supplying data to sculpt the UI experience via data-driven tactics